# HP printer shows it's connected to my network, but my computer can't see it. How do I fix this?

Tags: wireless-networking, printer

I have an HP LaserJet model that is connected to my network SSID but when I punch in my printer's IP address into the HP driver installer, the software is unable to detect my printer. When I try to ping the IP address, it says "unreachable."

I'm using Windows 11, but other people on my network have reported issues with Mac.

How do I fix this issue?

Answer (score 2):

Log into your wireless router (or contact someone who can) and make sure any feature called "AP Isolation" is disabled.  With this enabled, nodes on that router can't see each other.

Answer (score 0):

A common issue is that (older) printers often can only communicate via the 2.4 GHz network while your Mac with Windows 11 is probably capable of using 5 GHz WIFI networks. Often the router's default WIFI configuration uses a mixed mode, resulting in some devices being able to "see" the printer on the network while others aren't. My recommendation is to split the 2.4 and 5 GHz networks into two distinguished networks or disable 5 GHz entirely (depending on your throughput you might not even benefit from 5 GHz).

Comment: My printer is set to use both frequencies.

Comment: I understand, but if the router uses a mixed mode then it still could occur that the printer is in the 2.4 G network while the Mac is in the 5 G network or the other way around. I've seen this plenty of times.